# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) en conexión a la base de datos

Tags: php

Mis credenciales están bien pero el sistema aun así no me permite conectar a la base de datos.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
   $servername="localhost";
   $username="root";
   $password="";
   $database="sistema";
 
     $conn=new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
 
     if($conn->connect_error){
         die("Conexión Fallida: ". $conn->connect_error);
     }
$conn->close();
?>
```

y el error que me arroja es el siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sacesm\sql\conexion.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sacesm\sql\conexion.php(7): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'root', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'sistema') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\sacesm\vista\busqueda.php(15): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sacesm\sql\conexion.php on line 7

Espera que se conecte a la base de datos para poder extraer la información que pase pero me sigue diciendo que tengo problema con las credenciales.

Comment: ¿Es esa base de datos? ¿Probaste cambiar "localhost" por la IP relacionada? ¿Intentaste crear otro usuario con los privilegios correspondientes?

Comment: Si, y sigue arrojando el mismo error

Comment: puedes agregar todas las pruebas realizadas al contenido ... quiero ver los diferentes codigo que implementaste en la pruebas que realizaste que has indicado antes ...

Comment: Si o si el Error que sale es que el usuario root no tiene permisos de acceso a esa base de datos ...

Comment: puede estar relacionado a tu setup local ... puedes dar detalles de que estas usando como entorno de desarrollo?

Comment: Es tu usuario **root**. He probado tu código y funciona correctamente.